# many pins, how to distinguish each pin?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

Please help me, I am stuck with this `MapView`:

I have a `MapView` and a small label under that `MapView`. On the `MapView`, I have many pins (`MKPinAnnotationView`), I know how to set the title and subtitle of each pin by using array, but I do not know how to distinguish each pin. I mean when user taps a pin, the label will show the title of the tapped pin.

Here is some of my code:

This is where I define the pin:

```
@implementation PlacePin

@synthesize coordinate,title,subtitle;
@synthesize nTag;

- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord{   

    self = [super init];    
    if (self) {         
        coordinate = coord;     
    }
    return self;    
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [title release];
    [subtitle release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

This is where I proccess the result from server:

```
- (void) resultCheck {

NSString *strUrl    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ServerAddress.com"];

NSLog(@"MapView - resultCheck: url: %@ ", strUrl);
NSURL *url          = [ NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];

//get the result from server
NSString *result    = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSLog(@"MapView - resultCheck: result: %@", result);


NSDictionary *dictionary = [result JSONValue];
NSLog(@"MapView - resultCheck: dictionary: %@", dictionary);





//process the JSON, get two parameters: xPos, yPos 
NSDictionary *value1 = [dictionary valueForKey:@"result"];
NSDictionary *value2 = [value1 valueForKey:@"post"];



NSArray *arrXPos    = [value2 valueForKey:@"xPos"];         //array of xPos
NSArray *arrYPos    = [value2 valueForKey:@"yPos"];         //array of yPos
self.arrName        = [value2 valueForKey:@"name"];         //array of name
self.arrPlaceInfor  = [value2 valueForKey:@"place_info"];



NSLog(@"MapView - resultCheck: value1: %@",value1);
NSLog(@"MapView - resultCheck: value2: %@",value2);
NSLog(@"MapView - resultCheck: value3: %@",arrXPos);
NSLog(@"MapView - resultCheck: value4: %@",arrYPos);



//get the xPos and yPos 
for (int i = 0 ; i < [value2 count]; i++) {

    //display the place depended on the xPos and yPos

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location; 

    location.latitude   = [[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrXPos objectAtIndex:i]] doubleValue];
    location.longitude  = [[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrYPos objectAtIndex:i]] doubleValue];


    PlacePin *mapPoint  = [[PlacePin alloc] initWithLocation:location];
    //set the title and subtitle of the pin depending on the result from server
    mapPoint.title      = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arrName objectAtIndex:i]];
    mapPoint.subtitle   = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arrPlaceInfor objectAtIndex:i]];

    [mapView addAnnotation:mapPoint];
    [mapPoint release];


    mapPoint = nil;



}
```

}

This is where I proccess the pin and set the label - where I am getting stuck :(

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 4_0){

    self.labelShortIntro.text = @"1111111111111";


}

//customize an annotation
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView    = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor                = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    annView.animatesDrop            = TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout          = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset           = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    NSArray *selectedAnnotations = mapView.selectedAnnotations;

    for(PlacePin *ann in selectedAnnotations)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",ann.title);
        self.labelShortIntro.text=ann.title;
    }
}
```

I hope this code will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, userar and WrightsCS. So quickly and so correctly !!! You really helped me out of the hell ! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{

    PlacePin *selectedPin       =     view.annotation;

    NSLog(@"Title = %@ Subtitle = %@",selectedPin.title,selectedPin.subtitle);

    self.labelShortIntro.text   =     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title = %@ Subtitle = %@",selectedPin.title,selectedPin.subtitle];

}
```

Comment: Shortly and easily to understand. Deeply thank you too, naveen. :)